# Child/parent inheritance

Tags: css

I have a child element that needs to inherit the height of a parent element way up the element tree. Is there a way to tell the child element to inherit a property from another element without specifying it for all parent levels up the tree?

Comment: No...there isn't.

Comment: A **direct descendant** of an element is a child.  `parent > child` ...`parent > child >descendant > descendant >` etc...

Comment: Only `#parent{height: x}`, `#child{height: inherit}`, `#grandchild{height: inherit}` etc.

Comment: If you are willing to position the child absolutely, and the "parent" (which is not the parent btw., but an ancestor) is the first element up in the tree from the child that is itself positioned, then setting top/bottom to 0 and height to auto could accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in short: **No**; it is not possible.

Only inheritable properties (some actually can't be) can be passed from *parents* to *children*.

From your question: "Is there a way to tell the ***child element*** to inherit a ***property*** from another ***element*** WITHOUT specifying it for all ***parent*** levels up the tree?":

Take it as: without specification = no legal relation *(to inherit a property as in a day to day reality)*.

In actual sense, only the *`<html>`* element cannot inherit a property.

All others need to be reference where appropriate and such properties must be inreritable for the transfer to be successful.

*... more [details](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade)*.